# strpos doesn't work with searching a term start with X

Tags: php, string, strpos

I need to change the length of decimal numbers according to $assetName. To do that I'm using strpos like so:

```
if (strpos($assetName, 'JPY') || strpos($assetName, 'XAG'))
{
    $decimal = 3;
}
elseif (strpos($assetName, 'OIL') || strpos($assetName, 'XAU'))
{
    $decimal = 2;
}
else
{
    $decimal = 5;
}
```

It doesn't work with XAG and XAU while it's working with JPY and OIL. If I tried with XAG or XAU $decimal becomes equal to 5. If I use AGU instead of XAG, it works when $assetName = XAGUSD.

I'm guessing X in the beginning causes the problem but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check strpos with strict type checking

```
strpos($assetName, 'JPY') !== false
```

Because when searched string happened to match at 0th index then its false in `if` statement but not false if checked with strict type comparison.

> **Note:-** Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the **haystack** string (independent of offset). Also
>   note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns **FALSE** if the needle was not found.